# Possible issue while uploading new app code to app store

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, archive

Ill keep this short as I just need quick confirmation I didn't just ruin my upload request.

I got my version update all ready via iTunes connect.  Then went into xCode, archived my project, went to organizer - archives and validated the archive, then uploaded it and it was succesffuly sent off to iTunes. In iTunes connect, I see the project's status is now at "waiting for review"

This is all fine, BUT I accidentally deleted the archive in the organizer- archives window in xcode... Will this screw anything up with the upload?

I'm asking this question out of paranoia, and would love it if someone could confirm / deny any adverse affects that comes with the deletion of an archive that was used to recently update an app in the app store via xcode.

Thanks for the read.

Comment: You should restore the deleted archive from backup (you do have a backup of your hard drive, right?). Without the archive you won't be able to symbolicate any crash reports your might get for this version of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's no problem. The archive is already uploaded to Apple and waiting for review. You only deleted the archive from your mac.